# AWS CodeCommit with git-remote-codecommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, git-remote, aws-codecommit

Im using windows and im trying to use git-remote-codecommit.

steps for HTTPS Connections to AWS CodeCommit with git-remote-codecommit.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-git-remote-codecommit.html

While fetching , this error shows:

```
git clone codecommit://MyRepositoryName

git: 'remote-codecommit' is not a git command. See 'git --help'
```

please help..

Comment: Does this page help you with your problem? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-grc.html

Comment: I have this same issue, uninstalled and reinstalled via pip3, python3 already in path by default, yet it still fails. Doesn't make sense. I am using Big Sur on M1 though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68169139/21669262 this is also worked for me ,Mac OS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar issue. It turns out that somehow the git-remote-codecommit extension was somehow installed but broken.

I fixed it by first

1. uninstalling: pip3 uninstall git-remote-codecommit
2. reinstalling: pip3 install git-remote-codecommit

The install will check to see if Python3 is in your $PATH if not you'll need to add it.

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I also decided to change my git installation by installed it via brew and then using a new terminal window: ```brew install git```

Comment: Feels like the same as rebooting to fix things but it worked!

Answer (score 16):

The other solutions did not work for me. I tried following [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-grc.html#:~:text=a%20CodeCommit%20repository-,I%20see%20an%20error%3A%20git%3A%20%27remote-codecommit%27%20is%20not%20a%20git%20command,-Problem%3A%20When%20you](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-grc.html#:%7E:text=a%20CodeCommit%20repository-,I%20see%20an%20error%3A%20git%3A%20%27remote-codecommit%27%20is%20not%20a%20git%20command,-Problem%3A%20When%20you) but it did not work as well.

What ended up working as doing a `brew install git-remote-codecommit` :)

```
$ which git-remote-codecommit
/opt/homebrew/bin/git-remote-codecommit
```

I am using a M1 Big Sur if that matters.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: I had VSCode's source control manager prompting that error to me although it worked in the terminal (M3 macOS). In addition to this answer I had to run `brew link --overwrite git-remote-codecommit`. Then restarting VSCode fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Need to run this command in terminal to solve this problem  `pip3 install git-remote-codecommit` or `pip install git-remote-codecommit`

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing this issue but it work after Force install **git-remote-codecommit**

```
pip install git-remote-codecommit --force
```

The same solution is given here as well.

https://www.miraclewebsoft.com/remote-codecommit-is-not-a-git-command-see-git-help/

Answer (score 3):

i try to uninstall git-remote-codecommit and find the path that it's installed

```
C:\Users\user>pip3 uninstall git-remote-codecommit
Found existing installation: git-remote-codecommit 1.16
Uninstalling git-remote-codecommit-1.16:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python39\scripts\git-remote-codecommit-script.py
    c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python39\scripts\git-remote-codecommit.exe
    c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages\git_remote_codecommit-1.16-py3.9.egg-info
    c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages\git_remote_codecommit\*
```

when i add this path to environment variable then it works.

```
c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python39\scripts\
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I installed the git-remote-codecommit using pip with --user flag which installed the package in the home directory.

`pip install git-remote-codecommit --user`

I fixed the problem by adding Python's Script path to the PATH environment variable.

`C:\Users\{HOME_DIR}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`

Comment: My issue was to also add the environment variable. Though my path was different, it was C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts

Answer (score 1):

Installing with superuser do (`sudo`) command worked for me. Details of why it works can be accessed here: https://github.com/aws/git-remote-codecommit/issues/4#issuecomment-889247512

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in Mac. I installed the "git-remote-codecommit" with homebrew (instead of using pip3) with the following command and it worked. With this approach, there is no need to set the PATH variable manually. You might see warning/errors along the process of the installation (installation takes few minutes so be patient). BTW, FYI - I have Python 3.9.6.

brew install git-remote-codecommit

Answer (score -1):

In my case I set-up the remote url

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://git-codecommit.*******/v1/repos/My-Project
```

I added a commit
and I push to master

```
git push origin master
```

and it works